# ADIF is set first or ADSC is cleared first?

Tags: adc, avr, atmega

I am using an ATmega8A for ADC conversion. I start ADC conversion by setting ADSC bit and wait till it clears by hardware to detect the end of conversion. I saw some people checking the ADIF bit to detect the end of conversion.

```
ADCSRA |= (1 << ADSC); // start ADC conversion
while (ADCSRA & (1 << ADSC)) ; // wait for the end of conversion
```

or

```
ADCSRA |= (1 << ADSC); // start ADC conversion
while (!(ADCSRA & (1 << ADIF))) ; // wait for the end of conversion
ADCSRA |= (1 << ADIF); // clear the flag
```

Of course, both of them work fine; I want to know which one occurs first, ADSC=0 or ADIF=1? And which one is better to use? The datasheet says "ADSC will read as one as long as a conversion is in progress. When the conversion is complete, it returns to zero." about ADSC and "This bit is set when an ADC conversion completes and the Data Registers are updated." about ADIF. Does that mean the value of data registers may not be updated right after ADSC is cleared?

I ask all of these because if I use checking ADIF to detect the end of conversion I had to clear it and this means one extra word in the flash memory and one extra clock cycle in program execution in comparison with just checking ADSC.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ADIF is the interrupt flag. Unless the associated interrupt is enabled, you need to specifically clear that flag as you’ve mentioned. ADSC is the conversion complete flag. Which is set first? Probably both as one would think there would be only one mechanism internally to flag completion.
I’ve always used ADSC. ADIF is used by those that don’t read the datasheet.

Comment: "ADIF is used by those that don't read the datasheet" - if you read the datasheet you'll find that ADIF asserts at the same time as ADSC clears, so using either is correct. What you will also find (as the other answer mentions) is if you are using any other mode than single conversion, ADSC can't be used to check if a conversion is complete. So the ADSC method works only in one specific case  whilst the ADIF method works for all cases.

Comment: Seems my subtlety got lost in translation!

Answer (score 1):

ADIF is good for when you are using free running mode. in this situation ADSC does not clear and stay high. so in between, if you want to perform a channel change, take a sample and back to default channel you dont have precise timing. you dont know when conversion ends, so perform a channel change. even if do that, you cant determine the result you read is related after channel change or it is for the previous channel